# Spring Hateoas ControllerLinkBuilder doesn't support composed annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-hateoas

The project I'm working on is explicitly using the APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE media type. To make it easier for our devs and limit the keystrokes I wanted to created a composed annotation that enforced the media type but allowed for the path to be set. I attempted to create the annotation

```
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public @interface JsonUtf8RequestMapping {
    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "path")
    String[] value() default {};
}
```

When I attempt to use this on my rest controllers I am reciving an IllegalArgumentException: 'uriTemplate' must not be null by the ControllerLinkBuilder provided by spring hateoas. I'm guessing this isn't supported at all. I think it would be possible if I rolled my own ControllerLinkBuilder that used some sort of multi annotation mapping discoverer instead of just the single annotation mapping discoverer that was coded to scan for RequestMapping. Is there any way to do this without having to write my own ControllerLinkBuilder?

Comment: Composed annotation are supported. Maybe we can find a solution if you provide some code.

Comment: Hi @zeroflagL, I created an example project here https://github.com/dwdking/example-hateoas, there are two controllers published localhost:8080/workingExample which works and localhost:8080/notWorkingExample which throws the exception. The exception is caused because DISCOVERER.getMapping returns null on line 143 in ControllerLinkBuilder and the UriTemplate then throws an exception because it can't accept a null value

Comment: This might be a bug https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/392